# UDF's vs Spark sql vs column expressions performance optimization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I understand that `UDF`s are a complete blackbox to Spark and no attempt will be made to optimize it. But will the usage of `Column` type and its functions listed in: (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
make the function "eligible" for `Catalyst Optimizer`?.

For example, `UDF` to create a new column by adding `1` to existing column

```
val addOne = udf( (num: Int) => num + 1 )
df.withColumn("col2", addOne($"col1"))
```

The same Function, using `Column` type:

```
def addOne(col1: Column) = col1.plus(1)
df.withColumn("col2", addOne($"col1"))
```

or

```
spark.sql("select *, col1 + 1 from df")
```

will there be any difference in performance between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over a simple in-memory set of 6 records, the 2nd and 3rd options yield relatively the same performance of ~70 miliseconds, which is **much better than the first (using UDF - 0.7 seconds)**:

```
val addOne = udf( (num: Int) => num + 1 )
val res1 = df.withColumn("col2", addOne($"col1"))
res1.show()
//df.explain()

def addOne2(col1: Column) = col1.plus(1)
val res2 = df.withColumn("col2", addOne2($"col1"))
res2.show()
//res2.explain()

val res3 = spark.sql("select *, col1 + 1 from df")
res3.show()
```

**Timeline:**
First two stages are for UDF option, next two for the second option, and last two for spark SQL:
[image: Timeline - first two stages are for UDF, next two for the second option, and last two for spark sql]

In all three approaches, the shuffle writes was exactly the same (354.0 B) whereas the major difference in the duration was executor compute time when using UDF:
[image: Executor compute time when using UDF]

Comment: I wonder if the Dataset alternative is as bad as the UDF approach in your example `df.as[Int].map(num=> (num, num+1))`

Answer (score -4):

Yes they are different,

The first is a udf which is a block box to spark.

The second is not a udf and is just using the built in functions of spark